# Recover data from USB flash drive with testdisk and photorec

Tags: partitioning, usb, data-recovery, usb-drive, testdisk

I have a 32GB flash drive, somehow it is no more working, it is detected as an 8Mb drive as fdisk -l shows:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 8 MB, 8454144 bytes
1 heads, 17 sectors/track, 971 cylinders, total 16512 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/sdb doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

When I use testdisk here is what I get:

```
Disk /dev/sdb - 8454 KB / 8256 KiB - CHS 971 1 17
Current partition structure:
     Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors


Partition sector doesn't have the endmark 0xAA55
```

Then I enter to quick search and it found no partition

After more deeper searches I found no partition and it says:

```
Disk /dev/sdb - 8454 KB / 8256 KiB - CHS 971 1 17

     Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors


No partition found or selected for recovery
```

Is there a way I can recover my data, I mean it seems a partition error but testdisk is not able to detect any partition table.

thank you

Comment: what about using `sudo photorec` and scanning the whole disc ?

Comment: the same result no files found, I guess  because it's scanning 8Mb and not the entire 32Gb available space, if you know how to scan the whole disc please let me know.

Comment: what's the output of  `sudo fdisk -l`,  to see if recognizes the partition or the whole space on the flash drive as 8mb

Comment: When running this cmd it's detected as a 8Mb drive and doesn't contain a valid partition table, please see the updated topic for entire cmd output

Comment: can you make a raw partition using dd following this tutorial
`dd if=/dev/sdb of=/path/to/raw/image/harddrive.img` https://major.io/2010/12/14/mounting-a-raw-partition-file-made-with-dd-or-dd_rescue-in-linux/

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me once and I was very confused because `fdisk -l` seeing a too small device doesn't make any sense. I opened the USB stick and saw that units in there were physically disconnected from each other, put only in part. I disconnected them entirely and then reconnected them to make the USB stick work again.

If you do this and it solves your problem, please recover your data, **then** open GParted, unmount the partition (right-click on it in GParted), create a new partition table and then create a new partition. This is to make sure your partition isn't corrupted.

Comment: Hi,
I did't got how you did, could you please explain what do you mean by " I disconnected them entirely and then reconnected them to make the USB stick work again" thank you

Comment: In my USB stick, there was a board with several chips clipped to it. Some of the pins were connected to the board, some weren't. I took the chips off the board, then I clipped them back into it.

Answer (score 0):

Your Cylinder/Head/Sector (CHS) seems incorrect. I had similar problem with my friends 16 GB USB. But when I did "Analyse" in TestDisk there was a warning in the output about the mismatch. Try this:

Run TestDisk `sudo testdisk` -> select the correct drive -> select the Partition Table Type -> now select Geomety to change the CHS values. Than in the next menu select "Head" -> enter 255 and "Sector" -> enter 63. Leave the rest at the moment as it is. Press OK to exit and do the "Analyse" -> "Quick Search". When done, press "p" to list the content and follow written instructions.